# I have two containers running in different different ports how to do DNS entries for two containers

Tags: docker

I have two containers running in different ports how to do DNS entries for two containers.

Eg: 38.57.6.72:80    1st container running on httpd
    38.57.6.72:8080   2nd container running on tomcat

If I hit www.abc.com it should reach 38.57.6.72:80 
If I hit www.xyz.com it should reach 38.57.6.72:8080

Please recommend the best way to proceed.

Comment: DNS doesn't work that way.  You can set both host names to point to the same IP address, but not distinguish on ports.  You would need some sort of proxy that can do routing based on the HTTP `Host:` header.

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure a proxy or else can you provide any document over it.